# Async and await in ListView and react native do not work

Tags: listview, react-native, async-await

I am trying to clone data in ListView in react-native. I want to clone it asynchronous so using  async and await keyword.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        isLoading: true
    }
}//constructor

async   getMovieAsync() {
    try {
        let response = await fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json');
        let responseJson = await response.json();
        let ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
        this.setState({
            isLoading: false,
            dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(responseJson.movies)
        });
    } catch(error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}//getMovieAsync

 componentDidMount(){
      this.getMovieAsync();
}
```

I am getting an error:
***Cannot assign to read only property 'regeneratorRuntime' of object '#' this._lazyCallableModules[name] is not a function***

Comment: What is not working?